# SSRS rounding to 2 when decimals

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I am currently working on a report in SSRS 2017 and what I am trying to do is rounding to 2 decimal places when I have a number with decimals and do not show those decimals when I get a INT like

12.132 - 12.13 
13     - 13

however when I add "0.00" to the format property fir thos int values I get the decimals like 13.00 and I dont want to see the zeros

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Image above, Amount column is data coming from Database, Column 
Round Amount is Rounded amount and Amount Formatted is your expected Result.

How did I achieved it?

Right click the field which you want to add the format and select the "Text Box Properties"

use "#,###.##" in the format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your math expression with a format to achieve the decimal placing you are after.

Like this :

```
=format(Fields!yourfield1.value-Fields!yourfiend2.value,"0.00;(0.00)")
```